# Failing code check for CS50P, "Little Professor" problem. Can' see why

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to solve the "Little Professor" problem from CS50P Problem Set 4. My Python code is not passing the "check50" automatic code check. It's failing on "At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9." Also failing at Level 2 and Level 3. The error message from check50:

> Could not find the following in the output:
> 6 + 6 =

> Actual Output:
> 6 + 0 =

```
import random
import sys

def main():
    level = get_level()
    generate_integer(level)

    score = 0

    for i in range(10):
        a = generate_integer(level)
        b = generate_integer(level)

        for j in range(3):
            ans = input(f"{a} + {b} =")
            if int(ans) == int(a + b):
                score += 1
                break
            else:
                print("EEE")
                if j == 2:
                    print(a+b)
            j += 1

        i += 1

    print(f"Score: {score}")
    sys.exit(0)

# Prompts the user for a level, n
# If the user does not input 1, 2, or 3, the program should prompt again.

# get_level prompts (and, if need be, re-prompts) the user for a level and returns 1, 2, or 3,
def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input())
            if level < 1 or level > 3:
                level = input()
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            level = input()
    return level


# generate_integer returns a randomly generated non-negative integer with level digits or raises a ValueError if level is not 1, 2, or 3
def generate_integer(level):
    if level == 1:
        y = random.randint(0, 9)
    elif level == 2:
        y = random.randint(10, 99)
    elif level == 3:
        y = random.randint(100, 999)
    else:
        raise ValueError

    return y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Code seems to work as intended when I run it. It seems that check50 is looking for a specific addition problem (6 + 6), but the code is supposed to generate a random addition problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the problem, don't rely on others to search for what ""Little Professor" problem from CS50P Problem Set 4" means in order to understand your question

Comment: You should not have `level = input()` in the `except` block. That will ask for an extra input that's never used, since it loops back to `level = int(input())`

Comment: This line is useless: `generate_integer(level)`

Comment: `j += 1` and `i += 1` don't do anything useful, since the variables will be reassigned from the `range()` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that the testcase is doing something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(0)
user_module.main()
# check output
```

Because if you randomly generate 3 numbers with seed 0, you get

```
import random
random.seed(0)
print(random.randint(0, 9)) # 6
print(random.randint(0, 9)) # 6
print(random.randint(0, 9)) # 0
```

Given the same [random.seed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed), randint will always give the same outputs in order.

The issue is this line:

```
def main():
    level = get_level()
    generate_integer(level) # !!! issue !!!

    score = 0
```

That value is immediately discarded, so you don't need it. It doesn't do any harm, it's just ignored. But it means that random.randint() gets called one extra time, so the numbers that get used in the code are the 2nd and 3rd outputs of the random seed, rather than the 1st and 2nd. The testcase is based around assuming that you'll give it the 1st and 2nd outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `generate_integer(level)` was useless code and was confusing the code checker.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: See how do I write a good answer [answer].